# Delimited file read to list instead of df

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

Please help make R read the file into a dataframe, not a list. I am trying the following code:

```
head <- c("y", "x", "Label", "NDAI", "SD", "CORR","DF", "CF", "BF", "AF", "AN")
data1 <- read.delim("image1.txt", sep = "", header = T, col.names = head)
typeof(data1)
```

But this had no effect.

Comment: dataframes in R are lists under the hood. Compare `typeof(mtcars)` and `class(mtcars)`

Comment: Can you share a sample data of `image1.txt`?